# Alternative for cv2 on Colab for Webcam use?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, google-colaboratory, webcam

I'm trying to use the webcam on Google Colab using CV2- I've looked everywhere for an alternative but all responses are unfortunately outdated or have redirected people to use web APIs which I do not have any background knowledge on using. Here are some examples of lines that do not seem to work.

```
camera_video = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

```
cv2.imshow()
```

Is there a simpler, updated alternative method to this? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding these 2 code cells from this [link](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/snippets/advanced_outputs.ipynb#scrollTo=2viqYx97hPMi) under the Camera Capture portion to your code. You can also find the code cells from the "Code Snippets" button on the bottom left corner of Colab.